# Yii2 Insert Ignore / Insert duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm relatively new to Yii2 and so far I'm enjoying it very much.
I'm however finding an issue related with Database Inserts, more specifically MySQL.

The question is fairly simple: I'm inserting values into a table and I need to check for duplicates so my idea was to use an **INSERT IGNORE** or **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**.

This is the code I'm using for the insert:

```
$db->createCommand()
->insert('sdg_fb_apps', [
'fb_id' => $app->id,
'page_id' => $page_id,
'name' => $app->name,
'app_id' => $app_id,
'app_name' => $app_name,
])
->execute();
```

I have to unique keys: id and app_id and if I run this code I'll obviously be thrown an Exception from Yii.

There's this extension but as far as I understood only works with Yii 1.0: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rdbcommand

I also found this code snippet on [GitHub](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5138) that looks like this:

```
class MyQueryBuilder extends yii\db\mysql\QueryBuilder
{
    public function batchInsert($table, $columns, $rows)
    {
        $sql = parent::batchInsert($table, $columns, $rows);
        $sql .= 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE';
        return $sql;
    }
}
```

I didn't understand however how to extend the Querybuilder, can it be through a component?

I kind of accomplished what I was looking for by doing a query to see if the app_id was already in the database before and then only insert if they don't exist, however this is supposed to have to scale to huge numbers and this method might not be the best.

Any guidance will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than one year passed and I found this open question here. I see this has some traction, so it's good to add a proper answer.

In Yii2 the idea is to find the model, check if exists and then save. The framework will automatically update or insert, here's a snippet I got from [Viewlike.us - Yii2 Insert and Ignore duplicates](https://www.viewlike.us/yii2-insert-ignore-duplicates/):

> ```
> $model = YourModel::findOne(ID); // findOne() searches for the table key, you can use find()->where('=', 'column', 'name')->one(); to identify the model.
>
> if(!$model):
>     $model = new YourModel();
> endif;
>
> $model->column_1 = 'text';
> $model->column_2 = 123; // integer
> $model->save();
> ```

Comment: Because who cares for race conditions, right?

Answer (score 4):

Since Yii 2.0.14 there is a [`upsert()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#upsert()-detail) method which may be used for this.

```
$db->createCommand()
    ->upsert(
        'sdg_fb_apps',
        [
            'fb_id' => $app->id,
            'page_id' => $page_id,
            'name' => $app->name,
            'app_id' => $app_id,
            'app_name' => $app_name,
        ],
        false
    )
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to your question is method *$db->createCommand()*. Internally it uses *$commandClass* public property that is by default *yii\db\Command*. You can change it in your app config to override command methods like *batchInsert()* and others. Following is a sample from my app:

```
'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'enableSchemaCache' => YII_ENV_PROD,
    'commandClass' => 'app\db\MyCommand'
],
```

And your command class might look like:

```
class MyCommand extends yii\db\Command
{
    public function batchInsert($table, $columns, $rows)
    {
        parent::batchInsert($table, $columns, $rows);
        $sql = $this->getRawSql();
        $sql .= ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE';
        $this->setRawSql($sql);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

But I would rather introduce separate method, e.g. *batchInsertUpdate()* or something.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things to consider and possibly better ways to accomplish your task but the most direct answer (based on the info you provided) would be to extend the QueryBuilder.

Simple create an app component with an appropriate namespace and extend QueryBuilder as you have shown above.

If instead you use an ActiveRecord model with your table rather than doing sql commands directly there are other ways you can accomplish your desired goal.

Answer (score 0):

For Yii 1 (Yii 2 should be similar) I inherited CActiveRecord then I copied the insert function to insertIgnoreDuplicates,
I did the following changes after createInsertCommand call:

```
/**
     * Inserts ignore duplicates a row into the table based on this active record attributes.
     * If the table's primary key is auto-incremental and is null before insertion,
     * it will be populated with the actual value after insertion.
     * Note, validation is not performed in this method. You may call {@link validate} to perform the validation.
     * After the record is inserted to DB successfully, its {@link isNewRecord} property will be set false,
     * and its {@link scenario} property will be set to be 'update'.
     * @param array $attributes list of attributes that need to be saved. Defaults to null,
     * meaning all attributes that are loaded from DB will be saved.
     * @return boolean whether the attributes are valid and the record is inserted successfully.
     * @throws CDbException if the record is not new
     */
    public function insertIgnoreDuplicates($attributes = null)
    {
        try {
            return $this->insert($attributes);
        } catch (CDbException $ex) {
            if ($ex->code == 23000) // ignore duplicated key 
            {
            } else {
                throw $ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Usage:

```
$x = new record();
$x->attr1  = 'val';
$x->insertIgnoreDuplicates();
```